# Is sequelize support joins with subquery?

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js, subquery

In my query, I want to use the sequelize with left join and subquery.

select category.id, category.name, images.tag_id
from table.category
left outer join(select tag_id, category_id,s3_image_url,alt_tag from table.images images.tag_id = 23 and images.name ILIKE '%fresh%' ) as images on category.id = images.category_id
where category.name in ('fruit', 'leaf','tree')

I want to convert this query into sequelize.
After my conversion also it's not working. Is it possible to use left join and subquery on the same sequelize query? if possible please some example

Comment: You need to register two models to be able to join them, one is for `category` and another one for `images` table

Comment: already we have a model for image and category, joining with a subquery is possible

Comment: In this concrete query you can just link two models and add conditions separately for both of them indicating `separate: true` in `include` option to perform LEFT OUTER JOIN